# Set value to one of the property in Java 15 record

Tags: java, java-15, java-record

I am using Java 15 preview feature record in my code, and defined the record as follow

```
public record ProductViewModel
        (
                String id,
                String name,
                String description,
                float price
        ) {
}
```

In the controller level I have the below code

```
@Put(uri = "/{id}")
public Maybe<HttpResponse> Update(ProductViewModel model, String id) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Controller --> Updating the specified product"));
        return iProductManager.Update(id, model).flatMap(item -> {
            if(item == null)
                return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.notFound());
            else
                return Maybe.just(HttpResponse.accepted());
        });
    }
```

From the UI in the model the value of **id** is not passed, however, it is passed as a route parameter. Now I want to set the value in the controller level, something like

```
model.setid(id) // Old style
```

How can I set the value to the record particular property

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can't. Record properties are immutable. What you can do however is add a wither to create a new record with same properties but a new id:

```
public record ProductViewModel(String id,
                               String name, 
                               String description,
                               float price) {

    public ProductViewModel withId(String id) {
        return new ProductViewModel(id, name(), description(), price());
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great to have a method like copy in Scala's case class.

Comment: Not there yet but...
https://github.com/openjdk/amber-docs/blob/master/eg-drafts/reconstruction-records-and-classes.md

Comment: You could also use lombok's @With annotation  - https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-with-annotations

Answer (score 9):

If you need to mutate an attribute, then you need to use a `class` instead of a `record`.

From the [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395):

> Enhance the Java programming language with records, which are classes that act as transparent carriers for immutable data. Records can be thought of as *nominal tuples*.

So, you'd better use a class if you need that behavior.

Comment: I'd also add that you explicitly named your class as a 'model' which generally implies it is mutable.

Comment: @stridecolossus No, it doesn't, not _generally._ In fact in domain driven design large parts of the domain model will be value objects that by definition do not have a behaviour and thus should be immutable (it is derived from the fact that for values there is no concept of identity other than the value itself).

Answer (score 7):

You cannot modify them. From the [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) page:

> **A record class is a shallowly immutable, transparent carrier for a
> fixed set of values, called the record components.** The Java language
> provides concise syntax for declaring record classes, whereby the
> record components are declared in the record header. The list of
> record components declared in the record header form the record
> descriptor.

From the Java Language Specification [Section 8.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/preview/specs/records-jls.html#jls-8.10) one can read the following:

> A record declaration is implicitly final. It is permitted for the
> declaration of a record class to redundantly specify the final

and

**8.10.3 Record Members**

> A record class has for each record component appearing in the record
> component list an implicitly declared field with the same name as the
> record component and the same type as the declared type of the record
> component. **This field is declared private and final**. The field is
> annotated with the annotations, if any, that appear on the
> corresponding record component and whose annotation types are
> applicable in the field declaration context, or in type contexts, or
> both.