# Prevent false positve null warnings from IDE with gson and notNull annoation

Tags: java, gson, lombok, notnull

I have a simple json object.

```
{"id": 1, "name": "John"}
```

My class for reading this object is the following.

```
@Getter
public class Foo {
    
    @Setter
    private long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

I am using lombok for generating the getters and annotating not-null fields with jetbrain's `@NotNull` annotation.

```
String json = "{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"John\"}";

Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(json, Foo.class);
foo.setId(42);
```

Reading the json works just fine.

The only problem that I have that I am getting an error from the IDE `Not-null fields must be initialized` from my `name` field.

It is technically correct, my `name` field is not initalized in the constructor.

However, I am using Gson to deserialize my object and know that `name` is never `null`. I do not want to create a normal object, just read from json.

Also I need the annotation `@NotNull`, because lomboks `@Getter` will generate me a getter with an `@NotNull` annotation.

I also have some cases where I want to replace one of my field (`id`) with another value.

I do not want to use a plain Java getter or remove the annoation from my attribute.

What can I do?

Comment: "and know that name is never null"; just as side note: Gson does not check this and ignores the `@NotNull` annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solution works with Java 14 or higher.**

One possible way is using a `record`. Instead of writing a class and generating the getter via lombok, it is also possible to do this:

```
public record Foo(int id, @NotNull String name) { 
}
```

It will automatically generate a method `name()` which has the `@NotNull` annotation.

If you later need to set a field of a record, you need to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65254270/11342225) and do something like this:

```
public record Foo(int id, @NotNull String name) {
    
    @NotNull
    public Foo withId(int id) {
        return new Foo(id, name());
    }

}
```

This will allow to modify the id later. Only disadvantage is that you need to type out the method to set the field (`withId`) and that you have a new record that you need to handle correctly.

```
Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(json, Foo .class);
foo = foo.withId(42);
```